# Delete old report files from PATH for x days in Perl

Tags: perl, logrotate

I have a script which should create a report on daily basis on some alarm data. These report files(.csv) will be stored in the perticular path.

Before generating the report, I need to look whether there is existance of any old files which are older than **x** days (passed as an argument to the script based on requirement).

Below is script to delete the old logs/reports.

```
...
use File::Find;

my $days = $ARGV[0]; #pass as a parameter, i.e., number of days

my $PATH = "/path/to/the/logfiles/";
print "backup path -> $PATH\n";

my @file_list;
my @find_dirs       = ($PATH);           # directories to search
my $now             = time();            # get current time
my $seconds_per_day = 60*60*24;          # seconds in a day
my $AGE             = $days*$seconds_per_day;   # age in seconds
find ( sub {
    my $file = $File::Find::name;
    if ( -f $file ) {
    push (@file_list, $file)
    }
}, @find_dirs);


for my $file (@file_list) {
    my @stats = stat($file);
    if ($now-$stats[9] > $AGE) {
        unlink $file;
    }
}
print "Deleted files older than $days days.\n";

#
# GENERATE REPORT CODE
#
...
...
```

This script works fine for me. I want to know whether we have any Standard Perl Module which will do the same operation which can act as logrotation.

Comment: What do you mean by "Standard Perl Module" ? A core module ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland -- Module which is available in metacpan.

Comment: I did a quick search for [log rotate](https://grep.cpanauthors.org/search?q=log+rotate) which shows that there are many modules that does similar stuff, but maybe not exactly what you do. For example: [File::Rotate::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RRWO/File-Rotate-Simple-v0.2.4/lib/File/Rotate/Simple.pm)

Comment: There are various log rotating services that do this without your program needing to administer it.

Comment: I second the advice to seek a ready solution, either on the system (like `logrotate`) or as a Perl module.  But, if you're doing it yourself you can save some work using [-M filetest](https://perldoc.pl/functions/-X.html), which gives the age of the file in days.  So simply `if (-M $file > $days) {..}`